delay with WT reconstruction on python using PyWalvelet (pymt)
I need to perform a wavelet transform on a time serie on Python using pywt. I used wavedec and upcoef on 2 signals : one with my entire time serie and the other one on only half of the serie. the results are matching but the curves have a delay of three points. I was wandering why and how can I make sure that my wavelet transform matches exactly with my time frame. Also, I couldn' t understand what is the parameter "take" in the functiun upcoef. I also have many questions about the computation of WT in Python. How can I inform myself more about the computation of the Wavelet transform.
I used the wavelet db2

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hello @Isolde Durand. Could you please provide us with an example of what you tried?
